# Paid subscription through social signup?

Tags: website-design, forms, signup-signon

I have a freemium platform, that currently allows only social sign-up (twitter or instagram).
We are now also offering paid services, and an option to upgrade your account.

There are two relevant flows we have:

1. Existing user which already signed up with social network - should we require an addition of password to the account?
2. New user that is not logged in and is signing up for a trial for the paid version - is it ok to let them signup through social network?

Comment: Why would you add entering a password when using social logins main advantage is that users don't have to trust you to keep their credentials safe? Loging in through a social network is a means of authentication, not authorization. Someone (identified by their social login) having paid is part of their authorization profile and something you can store and use regardless of the way they were authenticated.

Comment: Agree with Marjan. One company that implements this is Spotify. They offer a free and paid service, and both can use social accounts without having to input any other credentials.

Comment: so whats the question here?

Comment: Agree with previous comments, the subscription type logic should not be tied to how the users sign up/login. This is more of a data structure suggestion but all forms of sign up should create the same user record in the database and the subscription type should be part of the user data.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Existing user which already signed up with social network - should we require an addition of password to the account?

No, that's not in your or the users interest. However, you may add an options for users to create a site specific account. Doing so allows for switching between login method. Sometimes users like to switch account they use to access the service, especially on a paid service.

A user may sign up using Google or Facebook account, only to realize it interferes with an already signed in user on a different device (wife's laptop or daughters iPad). The option to switch between accounts would then help the users to manage their sign in experience.

> 1. New user that is not logged in and is signing up for a trial for the paid version - is it ok to let them signup through social network?

Yes! It's actually a preferred method. Users already manage too many site centric username/password logins. Using a third party identity provider makes it easier for users of the service, and avoid your service to send too many "forgot password" links via e-mail.